# Converting DataFrame to ResultSet in Spark java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to convert `DataFrame` to `ResultSet` in Spark java?

I have one function that only allows `ResultSet` as an input parameter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it.  Good Luck!

Comment: Can you not write another function that accepts an RDD or a DataFrame? There does not appear to be a mapping from DataFrame to ResultSet as a DataFrame is a Spark collection object, and therefore does not "reside completely on the driver node" like a ResultSet would.